# Why dynamically create framelayout?

Tags: android

I am trying to understand how the Tinder like/dislike card system works by looking through this example on GitHub: https://github.com/kikoso/Swipeable-Cards/blob/master/AndTinder/src/main/java/com/andtinder/view/CardStackAdapter.java. I understand the importance of BaseAdapters and populating the view/card with the necessary info. This part of the code that is confusing the hell out of me is this:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    FrameLayout wrapper = (FrameLayout) convertView;
    FrameLayout innerWrapper;
    View cardView;
    View convertedCardView;
    if (wrapper == null) {
        wrapper = new FrameLayout(mContext);
        wrapper.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.card_bg);
        if (shouldFillCardBackground()) {
            innerWrapper = new FrameLayout(mContext);
            innerWrapper.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.card_bg));
            wrapper.addView(innerWrapper);
        } else {
            innerWrapper = wrapper;
        }
        cardView = getCardView(position, getCardModel(position), null, parent);
        innerWrapper.addView(cardView);
    } else {
        if (shouldFillCardBackground()) {
            innerWrapper = (FrameLayout) wrapper.getChildAt(0);
        } else {
            innerWrapper = wrapper;
        }
        cardView = innerWrapper.getChildAt(0);
        convertedCardView = getCardView(position, getCardModel(position), cardView, parent);
        if (convertedCardView != cardView) {
            wrapper.removeView(cardView);
            wrapper.addView(convertedCardView);
        }
    }
    return wrapper;
}
```

Why are FrameLayouts being created dynamically? It seems like multiple FrameLayouts are being made with wrapper and inner wrapper? What does wrapper even mean? Why are classes like shouldFillCardBackground() used but not even defined anywhere in the repository?

Comment: `shouldFillCardBackground()` is defined below that piece of code.

Comment: @gipi Oops you are correct. If that class always returns true then why are there if else statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, it is important to notice that the `CardStackAdapter` you link to is abstract, so it will never be instantiated directly. Rather, the class `SimpleCardStackAdapter` will be used for instance.

That said, lets get the purpose of the method clear; The `getView()` method's purpose is to create and populate a view for the given position.

Creating layouts can be done either by inflating them from xml, or otherwise, by creating them in code. The latter is happening here. The main reason that they create the layout dynamically, is to keep things dynamic. The exact views in the layout depend on some configurations which are checked at runtime (in the method `shouldFillCardBackground()`). Note that this could also be achieved by creating the layout in xml, then inflate it, and dynamically hide/show (or remove/add) views and layouts. The auther of the code simply chose to do it in code.

A wrapper is an object (in this case a layout) which does not much more that holding other objects (other layouts). In the context of layouts, they are usually used to add some kind of background or padding. That is also what is happening here.

`shouldFillCardBackground()` is a method, not a class, and it is definitely defined: in line 71.

*It is important to realize that it seems that the main puropose of this code is to be an example, a demo. It is possible it is not fully functional and that not everything is implemented the best way (for instance, `shouldFillCardBackground()` returns true by default).*

Comment: You are very helpful! I am still a beginner in Java and Android programming. One more question, what is the purpose of an abstract class such as CardStackAdapter if it is not instantiated directly?

Comment: In an abstract class it is possible to already call a method, but not define it yet (this happens here with `getCardView()`). You force the child implementations to implement that method. Main purpose is to move common code to one single place (the abstract class), and to keep implementation details separated in the children.